# Java command not working and keep on running for infinite

Tags: java

I am trying to execute the java command but every commands  its goes for infinite loop.
for example

> 1.java -version
>
> 2.java -help

above both commands keep on running and never returns a result this problem occurs from today morning for every java commands ex : jps,jconsole etc.

->JAVA_HOME and PATH variable already defined.

> which java
>
> ~/Java/jdk1.8.0_102/bin/java

and

> echo $JAVA_HOME
>
> /home/arc/Java/jdk1.8.0_102

and

> file /home/arc/Java/jdk1.8.0_102/bin/java
>
> /home/arc/Java/jdk1.8.0_102/bin/java: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.9, not stripped

Comment: I would A) really invoke that binary manually, using the full path B) run a command such as `file abs/path/to/java` to ensure that this file is really a binary ... but beyond that, it is almost impossible to help with such questions. One needs to have access to your system to figure the root cause of this problem.

Comment: thanks Ghost here is output looks like they are binary 
 file /home/arc/Java/jdk1.8.0_102/bin/java
/home/arc/Java/jdk1.8.0_102/bin/java: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.9, not stripped

Comment: It sounds like you have a sh file or link or something that calls itself, ie. `java`.

Comment: @SteveSmith here I am trying manually on terminal

Comment: @GhostCat I am posting question here first time so don't know much about posting etiquette.

Comment: @Sanjay That is because you posted first. Instead of first stepping back and reading through [help].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is with GLIBC-2.12, recently I installed GLIBC-2.14 manually ,problem arise due to conflicting between them.